# Why is the ImageView overlapping the UI?

Tags: android, xml, layout, imageview

I added an ImageView to the top of the main activity.I want to know is there a property I'm missing or one that is causing the overlap? Is there a way to fix this without changing the relative layout? I have posted the XML below.

So initially the UI looks like this:

[image: Normal:]

And after adding the ImageView it overlaps the input boxes completely:

[image]

```
 <ScrollView 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
     >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/ductDepth"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/calc"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"

        android:layout_marginBottom="37dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/enter_duct_depth_mm"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:singleLine="true" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/offDepth"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/ductDepth"
        android:layout_marginBottom="14dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/enter_offset_depth_mm"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:singleLine="true" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/offLength"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/offDepth"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/enter_offset_length_mm"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:singleLine="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/offDepth"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/offDepth"
        android:text="Depth:"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/ductDepth"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/ductDepth"
        android:text="Duct Depth:"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/offLength"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/offLength"
        android:text="Length:"
        android:textSize="30sp" />



    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager     
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/calc" >

    <!--
    This title strip will display the currently visible page title, as well as the page
    titles for adjacent pages.
    -->

    <android.support.v4.view.PagerTitleStrip
        android:id="@+id/pager_title_strip"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:background="#33b5e5"
        android:paddingBottom="4dp"
        android:paddingTop="4dp"
        android:textColor="#fff" />

</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="700dp"
        android:layout_height="700dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:src="@drawable/mark3" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/calc"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="26dp"
        android:background="@drawable/calcbttrans" />

</RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: that's what a relative layout does.

Comment: So if there a way to fix this..or will I have to change the layout?

Comment: the funny thing is that you correctly use the layout_above and such parameters for your other view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a relative layout which can place ui elements above of others, for your situation I recommend a linear layout that can place ui elements vertically or horizontally.

Comment: So if I change the tags to a linear layout,it won't overlap like this? Does this effect my layout if its wrapped in a scroll view?

Comment: You should be able to have a linear layout in a scroll view work just fine. The button however will need to stay in a relative layout to be on the bottom unless you are fine with it not being on the very bottom of the screen.

Comment: I don't think attributes like "android:layout_marginBottom" will work in a linear layout the same as they do in the relative layout, you will need to make some changes and experiment to get what you want.